# Apache Storm - Error when "mvn clean install"

Tags: maven, hadoop, bigdata, pom.xml, apache-storm

Im configured Apache Storm 0.9.2. I ran nimbus, supervisor and UI, i all ok.
Im configured Maven, Java.

I want to run the example "storm-starter" from: 
https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter

I have this error when i ran: "mvn clean install -DskipTests=true"

```js
Storm .............................................. SUCCESS [  3.983 s]
[INFO] maven-shade-clojure-transformer .................... SUCCESS [  4.242 s]
[INFO] storm-maven-plugins ................................ SUCCESS [  5.402 s]
[INFO] Storm Core ......................................... SUCCESS [01:10 min]
[INFO] storm-starter ...................................... SUCCESS [ 11.801 s]
[INFO] storm-kafka ........................................ FAILURE [  1.247 s]
[INFO] storm-hdfs ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-hbase ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:37 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-16T08:57:15-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 44M/128M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project storm-kafka: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/emiliano/Documents/AmbienteStorm/ejemplos/storm/external/storm-kafka/src/jvm/storm/kafka/ExponentialBackoffMsgRetryManager.java:[159,24] cannot find symbol
```

This is the POM.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with
this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
(the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
<artifactId>storm</artifactId>
<groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
<version>0.10.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
<artifactId>storm-starter</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>storm-starter</name>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.testng</groupId>
<artifactId>testng</artifactId>
<version>6.8.5</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
<artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
<artifactId>fest-assert-core</artifactId>
<version>2.0M8</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
<artifactId>jmock</artifactId>
<version>2.6.0</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
<artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
<version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
<artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
<version>${project.version}</version>
<!-- keep storm out of the jar-with-dependencies -->
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
<version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
<artifactId>guava</artifactId>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src/jvm</sourceDirectory>
<testSourceDirectory>test/jvm</testSourceDirectory>
<resources>
<resource>
<directory>${basedir}/multilang</directory>
</resource>
</resources>
<plugins>
<!--
Bind the maven-assembly-plugin to the package phase
this will create a jar file without the storm dependencies
suitable for deployment to a cluster.
-->
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<descriptorRefs>
<descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
</descriptorRefs>
<archive>
<manifest>
<mainClass />
</manifest>
</archive>
</configuration>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>make-assembly</id>
<phase>package</phase>
<goals>
<goal>single</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>com.theoryinpractise</groupId>
<artifactId>clojure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<extensions>true</extensions>
<configuration>
<sourceDirectories>
<sourceDirectory>src/clj</sourceDirectory>
</sourceDirectories>
</configuration>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>compile</id>
<phase>compile</phase>
<goals>
<goal>compile</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.2.1</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<goals>
<goal>exec</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
<executable>java</executable>
<includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
<includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
<classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
<mainClass>${storm.topology}</mainClass>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: The error message is truncated : `cannot find symbol...`. Can you provide the end of error message ? It looks like you need to provide storm-kafka which is an external package.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/apache/storm/commit/fd066985a74c3140f61a465cfc49c83a6ddfa713

You are enforced to use JDK 1.7 as the minimum requirement for storm-kafka.

Comment: Correct, I had the same behavior, this comment hinted at solving this problem. More detailed: In the pom.xml, change the maven-plugin configuration to have version "1.7" instead of "1.6" as source and target values and make sure to be running Java 1.7 (e.g., on a Mac, this is something along the lines of "export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home") before running Maven.